# Is it possible to sysprep a wim file after it is captured?

Tags: windows-10, sysprep, dism

I know what I am supposed to do: Run sysprep and then capture the image.

I know that you can do a lot of offline work on a WIM file using DISM. I know you can mount, edit, and unmount a WIM.

Is there some creative way to perform the sysprep steps on a WIM file that was captured from a production system?

I've looked far and wide but I've only seen people talking about the Microsoft way of doing things.

Comment: Interesting question. I don’t have an answer. But I am curious why this is necessary? Can’t you just boot the original machine back up and take a new image? Or, just boot the image on a new machine and `sysprep` it then. Either way, it sure seems easier to just make a new .wim.

Comment: I don't want to sysprep a system that someone is using and go through the set up process again. Booting it in a VM and syspreping from there might be a viable solution but that would take much more time than running a procedure directly on the WIM. There is also a chance that the image won't boot on dissimilar hardware.